# Spacy - custom stop words are not working

Tags: nlp, spacy, stop-words

I am trying to add custom STOP_WORDS to spacy.
The following code shall add the custom STOP_WORD "Bestellung" to the standard set of STOP_WORDS.
The problem I have is, that the adding works,i.e. the set contains "Bestellung" after adding it but when testing the custom stopword "Bestellung" with .is_stop, python returns FALSE.

Another test with an default STOP_WORD (i.e. it is standard in STOP_WORDS) "darunter" returns TRUE. I dont get it, beacause both words "Bestellung" and "darunter" are in the same set of STOP_WORDS.

Does anyone have an idea why it behaves like that?

Thank you

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.de.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

STOP_WORDS.add("Bestellung")
print(STOP_WORDS) #Printing STOP_WORDS proofs, that "Bestellung" is part of the Set "STOP_WORDS". Both tested words "darunter" and "Bestellung" are part of it.
nlp=spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
print(nlp.vocab["Bestellung"].is_stop) # return: FALSE
print(nlp.vocab["darunter"].is_stop) # return: TRUE
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is related to a bug in previous spaCy models. Works well in latest spaCy.
Example on English model:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
>>> STOP_WORDS.add("Bestellung")
>>> print(nlp.vocab["Bestellung"].is_stop)
True
```

In case you want to fix this on your existing spaCy, you can use this work around, which alters the is_stop attribute on the words present in STOP_WORDS.

```
nlp.vocab.add_flag(lambda s: s.lower() in spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS, spacy.attrs.IS_STOP)
```

This is mentioned in this [spaCy issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/922#issuecomment-360135141) on Github

Comment: Dear DhruPathak, that didn’t do the trick. But nlp.vocab[„String“].is_stop=true worked well. I combined it with a for loop for my custom list of stopwords. Thanks